# Cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a problem when i try to concatenate train set and validation set. I split my dataset into train set, validation set and test set. Then i scale them with 'StandardScaler()':

```
X_train, X_test, t_train, t_test = train_test_split(x, t, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
X_train, X_valid, t_train, t_valid = train_test_split(X_train, t_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_valid = sc.transform(X_valid)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Then after model selection i want concatenate training and validation set:

```
X_train = pd.concat([X_train, X_valid])
t_train = pd.concat([t_train, t_valid])
```

But it doesn't work. I give me that error:

```
cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Why you want to concatenate the training and validation sets? You should't do that. Kindly read a bit about the reasons of train test split.
After model selection you test your model with the test set or validation set.
After that you deploy the model, so you train over your whole data.
I feel you bit confuse here. Regards.

Comment: I want to merge validation and training  set to fit better my best model that i choice in model selection. After this i want test it with test set. Test set is a test that i never used it during model selection. Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

`X_train`, `X_valid`, `t_train`, `t_valid` are all numpy arrays so they need to be concatenated using numpy:

```
X_train = np.concatenate([X_train, X_valid])
t_train = np.concatenate([t_train, t_valid])
```

As suggested in the comments it is most likely not a good idea to merge train and validation sets together. Make sure you understand why datasets are split into training, testing and validation parts. You can apply cross validation to use all the data for train/test/valid in multiple steps.

Comment: I want to merge validation and training set to fit better my best model that i choice in model selection. After this i want test it with test set. Test set is a test that i never used it during model selection. Is it a bad idea? my professor taught me to do it this way. Btw your solution doesn't work. It gives me that error: " module 'numpy' has no attribute 'concat' "